# Displaying bounding rectangle in shapes in paperjs

Tags: canvas, paperjs

I am trying to display the bounds on a `Circle` shape. But since the `strokewidth` is a bit high, the `bounding` rectangle is displaying inside the circle. So, instead of bounds, I tried to use `strokeBounds`, but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
var centerPoint = new Point(100, 100);
var centerCircle = new Path.Circle(centerPoint, 25);
centerCircle.strokeColor = '#000';
centerCircle.strokeWidth = 10;
centerCircle.bounds.selected = true;
centerCircle.strokeBounds.selected = true;
```

Here is the [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/dZDBCsIwDIZfpcTDJozRDbxMvLgXEDx4cB66NrCx2Uqa6UF8dzuHMFEvIQnf9xNyB6vOCAXsO2TdQALamXGuqLJXRUKjZaSday2LjbB4E68+zqRMRCjL9SdZtqR7fKOKm3TaxLOgROSryZs7qWdyHZaudxT8aCGljP5Rh9ZwE6hMfhO1G6zxqcceNaMJFNOA/5K2v+nwiZpQdZfxYA/FEbIcTo8n) link to my code.

Here `centerCircle.strokeBounds.selected` is coming out to be undefined. How can I correctly display the bounding rectangle in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I also answered in the Github [issue](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1507).

A workaround could be to draw a rectangle using strokebounds and to select it instead.

```
var bounds = new Path.Rectangle(centerCircle.strokeBounds);
bounds.selected = true;
```

See this [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/dZCxDoIwEIZfpTkHMCGkkLhgXOQFjA4O4lDKRQjYmvbQwfjuFhoUB5fm2nzf3z/3BCWuCBkcWiRZQwRSV8P9LgyTqAjNTjeK2IYpfLBxDhPOI+aO5bowhfqSeWNkhxMqqI79SzgLili68t7ciS0Z3WKuO22cHyw458E/6thUVDsq4SMxdSh1ryo7/32PkoS6fAr8pGxH3FfxamyxcwZWLoNMj2u3jdKgaG9DcQvZCZIUzq83) for a demonstration.

Comment: this is not an answer worth posting. if you have any answer post it completely otherwise try commenting it.

Comment: Oh ok, I edited my answer to show the content in this post.